# How to get Users with Role permissions

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman, rest, azure-rest-api

I am using this [subscription api][https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01] to get the azure subscription details. but in the response we are getting authorization source has role based. How can we fetch the users present in that subscription and what are there permissions(ex- owner, reader)

[image]

Comment: You can use this API to get all role assignment of your subscription:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest 
But it is not so convenient as you can only get user ID and role defination ID, you will need to do some other actions if you want to get user and role display name.

It will be much easier to get all the information you want if you use Azure PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks @StanleyGong but we need a Api to do this action

Comment: Welcome, so do you have any more questions about it? If not, I'll summarize it as an answer :)

Comment: @StanleyGong you have mentioned that we need to do some other actions to get user and role display name please can i know what are that actions?

Comment: Hi @KrishnareddyChinthireddy, Sure, I have posted all steps to get Azure subscription role assignments. Could you pls accept it if it helps you?

Comment: HI @StanleyGong Thanks a lot i have gone through the apis and it helped me a lot
a quick small query by passing the role defination id in 1st api we are getting all the users list. is there any filter or parameter so i can get only my role assignment(i mean by passing user mail id has param not by passing object id)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228789/discussion-between-krishnareddy-chinthireddy-and-stanley-gong).

Comment: May I know if you have any other questions? If not, please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer.If you accept answers on time, others will be more glad you assist you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest) to get the role assignment of your subscription, just as below:
[image]

Each item record presents a role assignment. And you can find `roleDefinitionId` which means the role you assigned and `principalId` means the role assigned to which Azure AD app or user.

So if you want to get the details about the role information, you should call the API below sparately:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/<value of roleDefinitionId>?api-version=2018-07-01
```

[image]

And if you want to get the details information of `principalId`, you should call [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) : [get directory object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) just as below:

[image]

If you just want to query a user/Azure ad application is assigned with subscription roles, it will be much easier as This API provides a `$filter` param for us, lets say if you have a user's object ID, you can filter this user's role by request below:

[image]